# How to find out which process attempts to install a driver?

Tags: windows-10

I'm getting this pop-up from time to time, maybe twice a week. Is there a way to find out which process does this?

[image]

Update: This turned out to be more difficult than suggested by the answer. The parent process is the "Device Driver Installation service". Is there a way to trace which process activated the service?

Comment: Maybe? Try using Sysinternals Process Explorer, it can show a tree of processes. The program requesting the driver installation probably waits for the installation to finish. // It’s probably some VPN software. Using any?

Comment: @DanielB, thank you! No, I'm not using any VPNs, whichever software that's doing this is at least unwanted, if not malicious. Hence my interest in digging into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer):

[image: Process Explorer: find window's process]

If you sort the *'Process'* column by relation (by left clicking on its header once), and then drag the marking cross (see image) onto that installer window, you can identify its parent process.

Comment: The parent process is the "Device Driver Installation service". Is there a way to trace which process activated the service?

Comment: That sounds like Windows itself was looking for a driver update and found this one. Do you have any devices in the *device manager* that report a special status?

Comment: I have dozens of "Unknown device" under "Other devices", no idea where that garbage comes from. Other than that - nothing. And I have automatic updates disabled, so it's unlikely that Windows itself could initiate this installation. But on the other hand, the appearance of the request doesn't coincide with me opening any specific application, it looks like a background task.

Comment: P. S. Thank you for helping me with this!

Comment: You could check the network related ones (device properties should give a hint as to what the device does) and force a driver update. One of these will probably pop up the installer above. If not, move on to the unknown devices. If you're sure the device that causes this is not required for normal operation, you could disable it. This should stop Windows from attempting to update drivers.

Comment: Thanks! Did  you manage to track it down? I'll update the answer with my previous comment if this was the solution :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but you've had great ideas and tricks that will certainly be useful to know. You might be right that it's one of the 20 weird "unknown devices", I'll keep experimenting. The pop-up only appears about once a week.

Comment: Alright, feel free to check in here while you're doing that :)